# How to change single primary key to composite primary key with EF Core

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I want to delete the single primary key Id column in a SQL table that has already been created and does not contain data and define a composite primary key instead.

My current entity definition is as follows:

```
[Key]
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public int Id { get; set; }

public long IpFrom { get; set; }

public long IpTo { get; set; }
...
```

And I want to update to this:

```
[Key, Column(Order = 0)]
public long IpFrom { get; set; }

[Key, Column(Order = 1)]
public long IpTo { get; set; }
...
```

I have already made the following definition using fluent api:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
   base.OnModelCreating(builder);

   builder.Entity<IPv4LocationEntity>()
     .HasKey(b => new {b.IpFrom, b.IpTo})
     .HasName("PK_TableName");
}
```

Then I used EF Tool to create migration files and got the following migration file.

```
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.DropPrimaryKey(
            name: "PK_TableName",
            table: "TableName");

        migrationBuilder.DropColumn(
            name: "Id",
            table: "TableName");

        migrationBuilder.AddPrimaryKey(
            name: "PK_TableName",
            table: "TableName",
            columns: new[] { "IpFrom", "IpTo" });
    }

    protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.DropPrimaryKey(
            name: "PK_TableName",
            table: "TableName");

        migrationBuilder.AddColumn<int>(
            name: "Id",
            table: "TableName",
            type: "int",
            nullable: false,
            defaultValue: 0)
            .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1");

        migrationBuilder.AddPrimaryKey(
            name: "PK_TableName",
            table: "TableName",
            column: "Id");
    }
}
```

I get the following error when I want to update the database with the EF tool even though everything seems right to me:

```
ALTER TABLE DROP COLUMN failed because column 'Id' does not exist in table 'TableName'.
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Did you checked your database? Does 'TableName' really have 'Id' column?

Comment: @Dmitry yes there is

Comment: Generate migrations scripts (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli#generate-sql-scripts) without applying them to DB, and inspect that scripts.

Comment: @Dmitry When I run this command;

`dotnet ef migrations script`

It throws an error like this

`Could not load file or assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this and running `dotnet ef database update` does not apply the migration.

Instead, generated SQL file from the migration and execute the SQL queries. Try doing this.

```
cd ToYourDbModelProject
dotnet ef  --startup-project ../PathToStartupProject/ migrations script previous_migration current_migration -o current_migration.sql --context Namespace.To.Your.DbContext
```